# Image Re-sizing according to Background Image in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiimage, crop

I have Two `UIImage`(`Uiimage Views`),in there One Is Back image and another in front Image. I had Change The Back `imageView` size dynamically.
Now I want To Re-Size depends on Back Image The Front Image Also size also Dynamically need to changed(Proportionality).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the Newwidth/oldWidth ratio and similarly NewHeight/oldHeight ratio of back image after resizing and before resizing and Use the same ratio to calculate new frame for front imageView.

For eg. 
new width of back imageview will be == NewWidthOfFrontImage/oldWidthofFrontImage*oldWidthofBackImage;

Similarly you can calculate new Height.

Please be more specific about your question too so that answer could be more accurate ?

Comment: My back image is size in 320*355,when i'm change the size to 200*200 in that time i had reduced some ratio,i need to reduce the same sizes for front image also.

Comment: so what i got is you need to maintain the ratio , for your case newwidth = 320/200*oldWidthofFrontImage isnt that working and then set the new frame to front image view too

Comment: lets discuss it overhere http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23473/discussionforaquestion

Answer (score 0):

Let the two images be img1 and img2.

```
UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
```

Make the rect of img2 in proporton to the img1. put these lines in the method which you use to change the rect of img1 dyanamically.

```
int conversionRatio = arc4random()%10;

img2.frame = CGRectMake(img1.frame.origin.x, img1.frame.origin.y,    img1.frame.size.width/conversionRatio, img1.frame.size.height/conversionRatio);
```

U can also use animation blocks to make this happen animated..